# Android 7 is not showing layer-list xml drawable?

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview, android-xml, android-7.0-nougat

I have the following shape:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:top="9dp"
    android:right="9dp"
    android:bottom="9dp"
    android:left="9dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#4d4d4d" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#4d4d4d"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

And it looks like this: 
[image]

And here is how I add it to the ImageView:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/couterImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:background="@drawable/ring_selector"/>
```

The ring shape isdisplayed on all devices that I have, Samsung A5, A3, S4 mini, S3 from Android 4.4 to andtoid 5+, but today I got an Lg Nexus 5x with Android 7 and when I run the app, the xml image is not displayed.

I found a way to display it but that means that I have to hardcode it's width and height and I dont want that. What seems to be the problem here? the phone, android version,the code? Any suggestions would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: "I have to hardcode it's width and height and I dont want that" -- your `ImageView` already hardcodes the width and height.

Comment: yeah, that's correct, that's how I can see the image on the screen

Comment: Then you may wish to edit your question to show the code that is not working.

Comment: Ok, i've edited the code, now this is the form that is not working

Comment: Try putting `android:top` and kin on both `<item>` elements, not just the first.

Comment: if I do that, the ring dissappear for good. I thisnk the problem has to do smth with android 7.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that i cannot figure out what was the problem for the "ring" xml code, but I found another way to draw the ring.

I dont know if the problem is from Android 7 or not.

So for those who have the same problem, here is a solution for the ring.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#4d4d4d" />
<size
    android:width="17dp"
    android:height="17dp" />
```